# Predicate to check each element of the diagonal of matrix NxN

Tags: prolog

I need to write a Prolog predicate to check if all element on the diagonal of matrix NxN is equal to the sum of all other elements in the same row.

For example:

```
check([[1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 1], [7, 8, 15]]) => true
```

Any help (tip, resource to read,...) is really appreciated.

Comment: I think I need to use recursion, but I don't know how to do this (algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

Well, think declaratively and break the problem down. You're going to need to break the matrix down into a list of lists and consider each row one-by-one, so you're probably going to need a helper function to pass the current index along, like so:

```
check(Xs) :- check_all(Xs, 0).
check_all([X|Xs], Index) :- 
  /* do work */
  Index1 is Index + 1, check_all(Xs, Index1).
```

`check_all` probably needs a base case, which should probably look like this:

```
check_all([], _).
```

So now you need to figure out how you're going to check a given row based on having it and the index, so you now need a predicate to check just one row:

```
check_row(Row, Index) :-
  ...
```

This predicate is going to have to take apart the list and add up the values and then compare them to the value at the index, so you have a desired value:

```
  nth0(Index, Row, Desired),
```

And you need some way to remove the item at that index and consider the sum of the remainder. In fact you know that if the remaining items add up to the desired value you, pass the test:

```
  nth0(Index, Row, _, Remainder), sumlist(Remainder, Desired)
```

So that produces in total:

```
check_row(Row, Index) :-
  nth0(Index, Row, Desired, Remainder), sumlist(Remainder, Desired).
check_all([], _).
check_all([Row|Rows], Index) :-
  check_row(Row, Index),
  Index1 is Index + 1, check_all(Rows, Index1).
check(Xs) :- check_all(Xs, 0).
```

I haven't tested this code so I don't know if it works, and I'm certainly dependent on SWI-Prolog's lists library, but I hope this illustrates the declarative programming process a little bit.

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ My shotgun technique seldom produces code that works on the first try, so I hope that will offset that I'm doing someone's homework for them. :)

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog' *library(lists)* implements nth1/3 and sumlist/2.

Nth1 can act as enumerator, yielding *both* index and elements, so a solution can be very compact.

Another key element it's [forall/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2), see the page for an enlightening example.

I'll let you combine these elements as an useful exercise: fill the ellipsis..., there will be another nth1, a sumlist, and an arithmetic to check that the summed is 2 times the diagonal element.

```
   check(M) :-
      forall(nth1(I, M, Row), (...)).
```

Drop a note if you need the code.